# Reducible and Irreducible Quadratics in $\mathbb Z_5[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

> Determine how many reducible monic quadratics there are in $\mathbb Z_5[x]$.
>
> Now determine how many reducible and irreducible quadratics there are in $\mathbb Z_5[x]$.

I know there are 100 quadratics in $\mathbb Z_5[x]$ with 25 being monic (I believe). I think there are 7 irreducible monic quadratics(degree 1 polynomials, $x^2+2,x^2+3, x^2+x+1$), thus there are 18 monic reducible quadratics. This number seems unreasonably high. Am I even close with this?

Comment: Show some of your work.

Comment: A quadratic has factor $\Leftrightarrow$ It's reducible. A reducible polynomial can be of the form $(x+a)(x+b) \mod 5$ , where $a,b $ are numbers $ \mod 5$. Counting multiplicites, there are exactly $25$ reducible polynomials.

Comment: @AlexKChen I think you're overcounting.  $(x+1)(x+2)$ and $(x+2)(x+1)$ are the same polynomial.

Answer (score 5):

A reducible monic polynomial is of the form $x^2+2bx+c$, where $b^2-c$ is a square, that is $\Delta=b^2-c\in\{0,1,4\}$.

For any of these cases, we can assign $b$ any value and determine $c$. So $15$.

In another way: a reducible monic polynomial has the form $(x-h)(x-k)$, where $h$ and $k$ are the roots. Five cases for $h=k$; ten cases for $h\ne k$, because
$$
\binom{5}{2}=10
$$
(the order of the roots is irrelevant).

Another way. The field $F_{25}$ with $25$ elements is generated by any root of an irreducible polynomial; there are $25-5=20$ elements that generate $F_{25}$, but the minimal polynomial of any of these $20$ elements has two distinct roots. So we have $10$ irreducible polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variant of egreg's answer.

The field $\mathbb F_{25}$ is generated by any root of an irreducible quadratic polynomial. Since all elements of $\mathbb F_{25}$ are roots of $x^{25}-x$, the irreducible quadratic polynomial correspond to the irreducible quadratic factors of $x^{25}-x$. Factoring out $x^5-x$, which is a product of $5$ linear factors, leaves a polynomial of degree $20$ that is the product of irreducible quadratic polynomials. Therefore, there are $10$ irreducible quadratic polynomials.

Comment: @egreg, sorry for misspelling your name, I didn't notice the autocorrector creeping in!

Comment: I never use autocorrectors: I prefer to be the author of my own typos. `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

> Now determine how many reducible and irreducible quadratics there are in $\mathbb Z_5[x]$.

Perhaps obvious, but so far it doesn't seem this has been answered directly.

As we know from the answers above, there is a total of $100$ quadratics with 15 reducible *monic* quadratics and 10 irreducible *monic* quadratics in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$.

This implies a total of $15\times 4=60$ reducible quadratics and $10\times 4 = 40$ irreducible quadratics in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$.

Correct?